# node.js asynchronous azure queue storage output binding

Tags: javascript, azure-functions

I am trying to create a JS function that reads a file from storage, writes its content to the database and pushes a result message to a queue. Reading and db processing are ok but nothing happens when writing to the queue.

The code is like:

```
    process(file)
   .then(() => {
      context.bindings.outQueue = { file };
      return context.log('File processing completed successfully');
    })
    .catch(err => context.log.error(err));
```

If I use context.done() instead, I get the following error:

```
Error: Choose either to return a promise or call 'done'.  Do not use both in your script.
```

In either case no message is written to the queue.
What's wrong?

Comment: So does `context.done()` work if you don't return the promise? Do you call `context.done` after assigning the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are most likely causing you issues. **First, you should be returning within the main scope of the function.** Not returning will cause your Function App to hang, which is probably why you tried adding context.done(). **Second, you should not call context.done() when it could return prematurely.** The error message you saw is trying to prevent you from doing so. **Third, you should be returning your chained promise instead of calling context.done()`.** This is what will let you write to the queue correctly.

To the first point: I think you're assuming that returning inside of `.then(() => { ... });` is returning for the larger-scoped function. Remember that the lambda function passed into the .then() method is just returning a fulfillment value, which is used in order to pass the result of one promise to another promise (docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)). As a side-note, I'd suggest against returning `context.log('File processing completed successfully');` (just call it, don't return it), as this is the same as returning void but leads to more confusing code.

To the second point: Calling context.done() inside of `.then(() => { ... });` is calling a method to indicate that the **main** function from a fork'd asynchronous function. This is dangerous because theoretically, at any point after `.then(() => { ... });` is defined, the main function code could be killed by that call to context.done().

To the third point: If you just call context.done() in the scope of the main function instead of returning the promise, you will have the opposite problem of point #2 (the main code will exit and stop execution of the fork'd asynchronous task before the asynchronous code has completed).

Here's an example of a simple JS function that waits on a promise and writes to a queue:

**Example:**

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
     context.log("Starting function");

    // Mock Promise
    let doWork = new Promise(
       (resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
            console.log("Work in promise");
        }
    );

    doWork.then(() => {
        context.log("Work AFTER promise");
        context.bindings.queue1= "Queue message";
        context.log("Message queued!");
    }).catch(err => context.log.error(err));

    // This is the correct scope to return promise
    return doWork;
};
```